# JDBC connection string with spaces on file path (sqlite, hsqldb)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, hsqldb

I have to connect to a database that is hosted inside a file. Instead of pointing to a port I have to point to a file like this sqlite connection string:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:database/users.db"
```

But I can't figure out how to specify the path when the path has spaces on it like:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Documents and Settings\\users.db"
"jdbc:sqlite:C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/users.db"
```

None of these work.

Preferably I also want to be able to specify this path in a manner that is system agnostic (ie works both on windows and on linux). Without needing specific processing on each.

Comment: What about using only the forward slashes without escaping any spaces?

Comment: yeah that also does not work.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: @NishantShreshth I did some more testing and you are right, without escaping space it works. I was having an unrelated problem that was affecting the connection creation too. In the end I had two bugs, but I thought I had only one. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried this "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Documents\ and\ Settings\\users.db"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Nishant was right, I don't need to escape characters or use backslashes at all. This works:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:/Documents and Settings/users.db"
```

I had actually tried that but another bug prevented me from seeing it working. I had two bugs, but thought that I only had one.

Answer (score 1):

we can also try double back slash, it work for me

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Documents and Settings\\users.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe JDBC escaping is with {}. So that would become

```
"jdbc:sqlite:{C:/Documents and Settings/users.db}"
```

or

```
"{jdbc:sqlite:C:/Documents and Settings/users.db}"
```

or a variation of that.

Comment: This is not what JDBC escaping does. JDBC escaping is only for some functions and SQL constructs that are explicitly specified in the JDBC specification.

Answer (score 0):

For the system independent separator you should use `File.separator` from the standard API:

[File (Java SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.

`File.separator` returns this `char` as a `String`.